# How can I get request url in spring expression language?

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

How can I get request url in spring expression language?

This is my piece of code from spring security configuration:

```
.antMatchers("/users/location/**").access("principal.locations.contains('locationIdFromUrl')")
```

My expression works but I don't know how get url variable after /location. 
I need this variable to pass it into contains method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL parameters cannot be accessed at Config Class, you can use filters to perform this task logically.

*Pseudo code*

```
.addFilterBefore(new DeviceResolverRequestFilter(), LocationAccessFilter.class)
```

Where **LocationAccessFilter** contains the logic of location access.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved my proble.

```
antMatchers("/users/location/{id}/**").access("principal.locations.contains(#id)")
```